# Iterate over an array of tags in Pug

Tags: pug

I'm trying to iterate over an array with objects that contain the tag and some data.

For example:

```
[
  {
    tag: 'img',
    data: {
      src: '...',
      alt: '...'
    }
  },
  {
    tag: 'h1',
    data: {
      text: 'A header!'
    }
  }
]
```

I have tried:

```
each block in blocks
  block.tag data goes here
```

and

```
each block in blocks
  block['tag'] data goes here
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I know that Pug accepts dynamic tags, because I can create a variable:

```
- const myCustomTag = 'h2'
```

and then use it

```
myCustomTag a header :)
```

but how can I do it in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, all I had to do was use hash and curly braces, like so:

```
#{block.tag} data goes here :)
```